# Why python does not release the memory?

Tags: python, memory

I create a list `fig_list` to contain many matplotlib figure objects, then i try to release the memory by below codes:

```
>>> fig_list
[<matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x20AE7070>, <matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x21A61F30>, .....]
>>> del fig_list
>>> import gc
>>> gc.collect()
44918
```

Then I check the Windows Task Manager, found that memory usage of `python.exe` is not decreased . Why? How can I force python to release the memory ?

(I use python 2.6.1 on Windows XP)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4949335/951890